# K-fold cross validation for hierarchical data sets

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation, validation

I'm currently working on a data set that contains a hierarchical data structure (i.e., GPS locations nested within individual animals). Does anyone know how to write R code for this type of hierarchial data structure? Also, I'm using a generalized linear mixed effects modelling procedure (lme4 package). My data is binary (0 = random location; 1 = used location) and is being analyzed using a logistic regression framework. I cannot find any R code on-line or R package that handles hierarchial data sets when trying to cross-validate the predictability of a model. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Andreas Alfons' `cvTools` package ([at least the development version](https://github.com/aalfons/cvTools/blob/master/R/cvFolds.R)) has a `grouping` option for the splitting which allows you to split on the animal level.

Disclamer: I've not used `cvTools` but rather my own code for a similar (many spectra of fewer patients) situation so I could parallelize  and customize in a more fine-grained fashion which data to keep.

Comment: Great! I didn't notice this before but will give it a try to see if that works. Thanks for the help!